# Ubuntu apt-get with .pac files

Tags: linux, unix, proxy, apt-get, pac

I would like to use Ubuntu's apt-get on my computer, which is behind a company proxy server. Our browsers use a .pac file to figure out the right proxy. In the past, I browsed through that file and manually picked a proxy, which I used to configure apt, and that usually worked. However, they are constantly changing this file, and I'm getting so tired of this that I would love if I could just somehow tell apt to use the .pac file.

I've done some research, but every thread I found regarding this topic so far ended in: 'it's probably not possible, but why don't you just read the .pac file and manually pick a proxy'. It's a pain in the neck and sounds like computer stone age, that's why.

I find it hard to believe that something as - what I believe to be, but I may be wrong - ubiquitous as the .pac method has not been addressed yet by Ubuntu. Can someone give me a definitive answer for that? Are there other distributions that allow that sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

2. The console’ish way

If you don’t want to use dconf-editor, or if you use another flavor of Linux, your can use this second method.

Create a `.proxy` file in your home directory. Have it only read/write-able by yourself, as we will store your credentials in there (including your password).

...

Optional step: if you want your proxy setting to be propagated when you’re using sudo, open the `sudo` config file with `sudo visudo` and add the following line after the other Defaults lines:

```
Defaults    env_keep += "http_proxy https_proxy no_proxy"
```

From http://nknu.net/ubuntu-14-04-proxy-authentication-config/